# Microsoft access connection error in python

Tags: python, node.js

import pyodbc

conn = pyodbc.connect(r'Driver={Microsoft Access Driver (*.mdb, *.accdb)};DBQ=C:\Users\kisha\Desktop\python\py_Databse\Database21.accdb;')
cursor = conn.cursor()
cursor.execute('select * from table [category]')

for row in cursor.fetchall():
print (row)

Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:/Users/kisha/OneDrive/Desktop/AllNode/addPython/category.py", line 5, in 
cursor.execute('select * from table [category]')
pyodbc.ProgrammingError: ('42000', '[42000] [Microsoft][ODBC Microsoft Access Driver] Syntax error in FROM clause. (-3506) (SQLExecDirectW)')

> > > 

Comment: Congratulations on your first question. Since you are new to StackOverflow, please go through this page https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask to learn about writing questions in an awesome way and apply these in your current question. It needs a lot of improvement.

Comment: Please describe your problem and format your question so that it's clear what is code or output and what is just your question. Describe what you need to happen.